# Android annotations @afterviews called multiple times when fragment added

Tags: android-fragments, android-annotations

I have a fragment that whenever it is added to the layout @afterviews is called.

So for example in the parent activity I check if the fragment has been created, if not inflate it. Then I check if the fragment is added to the layout, if not add it and show the new fragment

```
@Click(R.id.tvActionFriends)
void friendsClicked() {

    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    if (friendsFragment == null) {
        friendsFragment = new FriendsFragment_();

    }

    if (!friendsFragment.isAdded()) {
        app.log("not added adding fragment");
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.layoutMainContainer, friendsFragment);
    }

    fragmentTransaction.show(friendsFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

The first time its clickd it goes through the lifecycle normally.

So now the user has pressed the back button I can see the teardown onPause() onDestroy() and onDetach()

So now the friendsFragment is removed from the layout but the class still exists.

Now the user clicks on a button again to show the friendsFragment, in the host activity. This time the fragment already exists but is not in layout so it is re added and transaction commits

now the fragment goes through the lifecycle of creation but @afterviews method is triggered twice, if a user hits back again and clicks the button a third time @afterviews will be triggered 3 times etc...

Here is the friendsFragment

```
@EFragment(R.layout.fragment_friends)
public class FriendsFragment extends BaseFragment {

ArrayList<String> numbers, facebookIds, emails;
ArrayList<Friend> friends;

@Bean
FriendsAdapter friendsAdapter;

@ViewById(R.id.lvFriends)
CustomListView lvFriends;

boolean gettingFriends = false;

@AfterInject
void initInject() {
    super.baseInject();

    numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
    facebookIds = new ArrayList<String>();

    friends = new ArrayList<Friend>();
    friendsAdapter.setItems(friends);
}

@AfterViews
void initViews() {
    super.baseViews();

    lvFriends.setAdapter(friendsAdapter);

    Cursor phones = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
            null, null, null, null);
    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
        String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));

        if (phoneNumber != null) {

            phoneNumber = phoneNumber.replace("+", "");

            numbers.add(phoneNumber);

        }
    }
    phones.close();

    getFriends();

}

OnFriendsListener onFriendsListener = new OnFriendsListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(List<Profile> friends) {
        for (Profile p : friends) {
            app.log(p.getName());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onException(Throwable throwable) {
        app.log(throwable.getMessage());
    };

    @Override
    public void onFail(String reason) {
        app.log(reason);
    }
};

@Background
void getFriends() {

    if (gettingFriends == true)
        return;

    gettingFriends = true;

    friends.clear();

    MultiValueMap<String, String> data = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();

    data.add("numbers", numbers.toString());
    data.add("facebook_ids", facebookIds.toString());

    ArrayList<Friend> resp = snapClient.recommendFriends(data);

    friendsCallback(resp);

}

@UiThread
void friendsCallback(ArrayList<Friend> resp) {

    if (resp != null)
        friends.addAll(resp);
    friendsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    gettingFriends = false;
}
```

}

As you can see the fragment extends a basefragment and calls the parent super.baseInject() and super.baseViews() to handle common class fields across all fragments

the base fragment looks like this, it basically just injects a few classes and logs the activity lifecycle of the fragment

```
@EFragment
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

@App
MyApp app;

@SystemService
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

@Bean
VideoCache videoCache;

@RestService
CloudClient cloudClient;

@Bean
MyResources myResources;

@ViewById(R.id.tvActionExtra)
TextView tvActionExtra;

SnapClient snapClient;

FragmentManager fragmentManager;

SimpleFacebook simpleFacebook;

void baseInject() {

    app.log("init inject " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());

    app.currentContext = getActivity();
    snapClient = app.snapClient;



}



void baseViews() {
    app.log("init views " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"attach " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    super.onAttach(activity);

    if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        try {
            MainActivity a = (MainActivity) activity;
            simpleFacebook = a.simpleFacebook;


        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
void toast(String message) {
    app.toast(message);
}

AlertDialog simpleAlert(String title, String message) {
    return MyApp.simpleAlert(getActivity(), title, message);
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"create " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"create view " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"pause" + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());;
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"resume " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    super.onResume();
}


@Override
public void onDetach() {
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"detach " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    super.onDetach();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(MyApp.TAG,"destroy " + this.getClass().getCanonicalName());
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

I dont' know if its an android annotation thing im messing up or something with the fragments, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not remember exactly, but i think we had some think similar issue before. Could you search in GitHub issues?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this may be fixed in AndroidAnnotations 3.3?

There was a pull request at https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/pull/1275, based on an issue at https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/issues/1264.

Comment: Not ActiveAndroid, but AndroidAnnotations. But yes, this should be fixed.